# System.Text.Json how to get converter to utilise default Write() behaviour

Tags: c#, json, converters, system.text.json

I have written a **system.text.json** custom converter for the `Read()` side of the custom converter.  However, for the `Write()` side, I would simply like to use the default Write functionality to serialise an object instead of having to hand roll the serialisation of an object.  I started with...

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Customer value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I had hoped that I could simply use the standard `JsonSerializer.Serialize(Customer)` within the `Write()` method.  Something like...

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Customer value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
}
```

However, that appears to be returning `null`.  I imagine that all I am doing is nesting the same behaviour.

As a sign of desperation, I have also tried deleting the `Write()` method hoping that the standard functionality would fill that gap, but I get the following Build error message...

```
CS0534  'CustomerJsonConverter' does not implement inherited abstract member
'JsonConverter<Customer>.Write(Utf8JsonWriter, Customer, JsonSerializerOptions)'
```

Newtonsoft.Json has properties called `CanRead` and `CanWrite` that can be set to False.  These force the converter to use the default converter functionality when deserializing and serializing respectively.

I'm hoping there's something similar in System.Text.Json?

---

### Update 1

Using **@Guilherme**'s suggestion... it part works.  However, that approach gives an incomplete Json object.

For background, when I Deserialize my original source Json, I am having to deal with a situation where the originating Json (over which I have no control), has a field that can be an empty `""`, or an object `{ "key": "value" }` or an array `[{ "key": "value" },{ "key": "value" }]`.  In the `Read()` (deserializer) I handle this and output a consistent array.

But now, when I serialise my resulting object, the Addresses array is always empty (blank).  Here's the output when I leave the `Write()` method empty.  Note that "Addresses" has no value or comma separator.

```
{
    "Customer": {
        "firstName": "John",
        :
        other values
        :
        "Addresses": "Phone": "01234567890"
    }
}
```

Do I have to roll my own JsonDocument and use that in the Write method?

Comment: It returns void. Did you tried leaving it empty?

Comment: Related or duplicate: [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182).  Agree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have worked out the answer.  :-)

When I request a instance of a `Customer` to be serialized...

```cs
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(customer);
```

... as the serializer hits the `Addresses` sub-class within `Customer`, it calls the `Write()` method of my custom converter, passing to it the current Json writer instance, the Addresses object instance to be serialized, and any converter options.

Quite simply, since I have deserialized the original quirky Json correctly in the `Read()` method of my customer converter and created an appropriate List<>, the `Write()` can simply serialize the `Addresses` instance using the Addresses class.  The code looks like this...

```cs
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Addresses value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the options also be passed along, as they will be lost for all subsequent children?

Comment: @Whosdatdev Not necessarily, if you're trying to Write as the .net God intended and not looking to overload that, you end up in a StackOverflow because it uses the JsonSerializerOptions that is self-referencing the JsonConverter.

Comment: @Tod you can cast the value to an object - `JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, (object)value, options);` to avoid the overflow, but still pass the options