# system text json use standard deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I'm using .net core 5, NOT USING NEWTONSOFT. I'm writing a custom serializer because the case output of my json is weird; but I don't mind using the standard deserializer.

I have the following code, following the microsoft guide on writing custom jsonConverters:

```
public class ThingConverter : JsonConverter<Thing>{
  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Thing t, JsonSerializerOptions options){
    // do stuff, this is fine
  }
  public override Thing Read(ref Utf8Reader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options){
    // i want the DEFAULT behaviour here.
  }
}
```

Would anyone know how to have the default behaviour for the reader?

Things I've tried:

- `return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Thing>(ref reader, options)` -> gives an infinite loop
- add `public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType){return false;}` -> Throws runtime error, cannot convert

fwiw, I'm using the declaration

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ThingConverter))]
public class Thing{
}
```

to register the converter globally.

Comment: It seems to be impossible to make `System.Text.Json` generate a default serialization for a type to which you have applied `[JsonConverter(typeof(ThingConverter))]` *directly to the type itself*.  There are ways to do it if the converter is applied in options, or on a specific property.  See: [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to change the property names only, use `[JsonPropertyName("Name")]`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties