# Avoid recursion with custom system.text.json converter

Tags: c#, system.text.json

On one of my classes I would like to do some post-deserialization processing.

The naive solution is

```cs
  [JsonConverter(typeof(MyClassFormatter))]
  public class MyClass { 
  
    internal void PostSerialisation()
    {
      //do stuff
    }

  }

  public class MyClassFormatter : JsonConverter<MyClass>
  {
    public override MyClass Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
      var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(ref reader, options);
      result.PostSerialisation();
      return result;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
      JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }
  }
```

This does not work, obviously, because it is recursive. As I have attached my converter to the class, when I call JsonSerializer.Serialize(...) or JsonSerializer.Deserialize my customer formatter is called and well, you can see where this is going.

Does anyone know of a way of calling JsonSerializer.Serialize or JsonSerializer.Deserialize that ignores my custom formatter and does the default serialization or deserialization?

Of course I could re-implement the serialization/deserialization code but it seems likely that there must be a more elegant solution. This must be quite a common scenario.

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to get the default serialization one you have attached a `JsonConverter` **to the class itself**.  See [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182).  But you can make System.Text.Json call a method after deserialization by implementing the [`IJsonOnDeserialized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized?view=net-6.0) interface.  Is that what you actually want?  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Maybe it does! I googled around but did not come across this interface. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: This works a treat. I just implemented this interface on my object. This is a classic case of asking entirely the wrong question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know as of .NET 6 there's no way to get the default serialization one you have attached a `JsonConverter` **to the class itself**.  The serializer will **always** use the converter when serializing or deserializing.  See
*[How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182)* for confirmation.

However, in your example it appears you only want to call some postprocessing method after serialization is complete:

```
public override MyClass Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
  var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(ref reader, options);
  result.PostSerialisation();
  return result;
}
```

This can be done **in .NET 6 and later** without needing a converter by implementing the [`IJsonOnDeserialized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized?view=net-6.0) interface:

```
public class MyClass : IJsonOnDeserialized 
{
    void IJsonOnDeserialized.OnDeserialized() => PostSerialisation();

    internal void PostSerialisation()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This interface is one of 4 interfaces that, when implemented, cause a callback to be made before or after serialization or deserialization.  They are a replacement for Newtonsoft's [serialization callbacks](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm):

- [`IJsonOnSerializing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsononserializing?view=net-6.0): *Specifies that the type should have its [`OnSerializing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsononserializing.onserializing?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-serialization-ijsononserializing-onserializing) method called before serialization occurs.*
- [`IJsonOnSerialized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsononserialized?view=net-6.0): *Specifies that the type should have its [`OnSerialized()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsononserialized.onserialized?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-serialization-ijsononserialized-onserialized) method called after serialization occurs.*
- [`IJsonOnDeserializing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserializing?view=net-6.0): *Specifies that the type should have its [`OnDeserializing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserializing.ondeserializing?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-serialization-ijsonondeserializing-ondeserializing) method called before deserialization occurs.*
- [`IJsonOnDeserialized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized?view=net-6.0): *Specifies that the JSON type should have its [`OnDeserialized()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized.ondeserialized?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-serialization-ijsonondeserialized-ondeserialized) method called after deserialization occurs.*

Note that all four interfaces have the following [restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> This behavior is only supported on types representing JSON objects. Types that have a custom converter or represent either collections or primitive values do not support this behavior.

Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/42uzer.

Comment: You're welcome.  If the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147532).

Answer (score 0):

Commenter dbc confirmed what I think I had already discovered, that once you have attached a custom converter to a class this problem is difficult to avoid.

However the same commenter pointed out that I was asking the wrong question, and that instead of a custom converter I should implement IJsonOnDeserialization, which worked well.