# How to put condition on Custom Json Convertor

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, system.text.json, jsonconverter

I have defined a custom Json Convertor for my DTO as below

```
public class CustomJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : class
    {
        public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            some code...
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            some code...
        }
    }
```

Then i am using it on my DTO as below

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter<StudentDTO>))]
    public class StudentDTO
    {
            some code...
    }
```

Its all working super fine.
Now All I want is At some place I want .net to use My JsonConverter and in other places i want .net to use default JsonConverter.
**How Do I Do it**

Is there a way where I remove the converter annotation from the DTO and instead Use "JsonSerialzer.Serialize()" and somehow I can tell it which converter to use.

Comment: You can use `JsonSerializerOptions` and add a new instance of your custom converter to the proerty `Converters`, it's documented on MSDN: [system-text-json - converters-how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0), and yes, remove the attribute on your class if you are going to serialize it in different ways. You can pass the `JsonSerializerOptions` as a parameter in the overload of `Deserialize<T>` and `Serialize`

Comment: You can't.  Once you apply the converter **to the class itself**, it will always be used in preference to default serialization.  See [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182).  Only thing I can think to do would be to subclass `StudentDTO` when you don't want to use the converter (or vice versa, when you do).  Or remove `[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter<StudentDTO>))]` and add the converter to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters` as recommended by @RyanWilson.