# How can I emulate deserialization "callbacks" in System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, serialization, system.text.json

I am attempting to have my object execute some logic immediately after deserialization. I am using the example shown on the following [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

The issue that I'm running into is that calling `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()` results in an infinite recursion loop because `Deserialize()` is called in the `Read` override. I know that I can get around this by implementing my own deserialize method - but that defeats the purpose of using this override, so I'm assuming that there's gotta be some way to keep the `Deserialize()` call in the `Read` override.

My deserialization test

```
    public void TestSerializationConverterCallbacks()
    {
        Animal a = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Animal>(SerializedData.SerializedAnimal);
    }
```

My serialized object

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(AnimalCallbacksConverter))]
    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "dog";
        
        public string Id { get; set; } = "123";
    }
```

My custom Serializer

```
    public class AnimalCallbacksConverter : JsonConverter<Animal>
    {
        public override Animal Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type type,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // Place "before" code here (OnDeserializing),
            // but note that there is no access here to the POCO instance.
            Console.WriteLine("OnDeserializing");

            // Don't pass in options when recursively calling Deserialize.
            Animal animal = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Animal>(ref reader);

            // Place "after" code here (OnDeserialized)
            Console.WriteLine("OnDeserialized");

            return animal;
        }

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            Animal animal, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // Place "before" code here (OnSerializing)
            Console.WriteLine("OnSerializing");

            // Don't pass in options when recursively calling Serialize.
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, animal);

            // Place "after" code here (OnSerialized)
            Console.WriteLine("OnSerialized");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may want to clarify what you expect to achieve with calling Deserialize inside Read.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You still need to return an object of type `Animal`. It doesn't make sense to completely rewrite the deserializer, so I'm calling Deserialize. My understanding of the documentation is that adding the `[JsonConverter(typeof(AnimalCallbacksConverter))]` attribute to the class should prevent this recursive loop from happening. The documentation for this override also includes Deserialize in the example.

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430420/how-to-use-default-serialization-in-a-custom-system-text-json-jsonconverter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use actual deserialization callbacks...

```
public class MyObject : IJsonOnDeserialized
{
    public MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public MyProperty2 { get; set; }

    void IJsonOnDeserialized.OnDeserialized()
    {
        //Code runs after deserialization is complete
    }
}
```

[System.Text.Json has an example of this about 2/3rds the way down the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0). Newtonsoft.Json doesn't have the limitations that System.Text.Json has, and can use `[OnDeserializing]` and `[OnDeserialized]` attributes that take a streaming context.

Comment: "2/3rds": this is the exact location: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0#callbacks