# how to set default value for object property with default value when Json property is null?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I use HttpClient in c# to get extra big and complicated data from a web service. I created the response DTO using the JsonToC# website and I am filling my DTOs using ReadFromJsonAsync. I am using **systen.text.json** as my serialization library, Sometimes when I am calling the web service some properties are null while their corresponding property in the object is not nullable.

```
public class InnerClass {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Quantity {get; set;}
}

public class ComplexClass {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public InnerClass innerClass {get; set;}
}
```

and I am getting responses like this:

```json
{
  "id": 1, 
  "innerClass": {
     "name": "test",
     "quantity": null
  }
}
```

so I am getting this exception on run time:

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path:

So I know that I can use the *DefaultValue* attribute but I should use it on all of my properties So I want to solve this problem from the root.

Comment: Define the type as int? instead of int which will allow a null.

Comment: I know that but the response is very complicated and I have no idea how many other properties are there that should be changed to nullable type.

Comment: You are looking for a simple solution to a complicated problem.  There is no simple solution, only a Kludge that will get you into more issues.

Comment: I am looking to create a new implementation of DefaultContractResolver or some other kind of helper class those can override it globally

Comment: If you use default value for int you will set the quantity to 0. How would you later be able to tell the difference for non existing quantity and the quantity actually being 0? I would suggest setting the properties as nullable. If you are not sure which ones, set all.

Comment: Do you want to do this globally, or for specific properties?  Also, do you only want to do this for non-nullable value types, or is there some need to do this for reference types as well?  Because value & reference types would need completely different logic.

Comment: @dbc all reference types are null by default

Comment: @Serge - I do know that of course.  But sometimes people want to skip `null` JSON values for reference types because they are initialized to some non-null value in the code.  They can do this in Json.NET by setting `NullValueHandling.Ignore` but System.Text.Json doesn't provide anything equivalent, so their code blows up on nulls when they port it over.  See e.g. [IgnoreNullValues does not work with non-nullable value types #30795](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30795).

Comment: @dbc Ok, understandable

Comment: @dbc  It just sounds funny "...how to set default value for object property with default value ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a default value for object properties when deserializing a null JSON property value, you could create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to) using the [converter factory pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#sample-factory-pattern-converter) that, for non-nullable value types, automatically maps `null` values to default values for that type during deserialization.

First define the following converter:

```
public class NullToDefaultConverter : DefaultConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert) == null;
    protected sealed override bool HandleNull { get; } = true;
    protected override T? Read<T>(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) where T:default => 
        reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.Null => default(T),
            _ => base.Read<T>(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions),
        };
}

public abstract class DefaultConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430420/how-to-use-default-serialization-in-a-custom-system-text-json-jsonconverter
    class DefaultConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> 
    {
        readonly JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions;
        readonly DefaultConverterFactory factory;

        public DefaultConverter(JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, DefaultConverterFactory factory) => (this.modifiedOptions, this.factory) = (modifiedOptions, factory);

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Write(writer, value, modifiedOptions);
        public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Read<T>(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);
    }
    class NullHandlingDefaultConverter<T> : DefaultConverter<T>
    {
        public NullHandlingDefaultConverter(JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, DefaultConverterFactory factory) : base(modifiedOptions, factory) { }
        public override bool HandleNull => true;
    }

    protected virtual JsonSerializerOptions ModifyOptions(JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        options.CopyAndRemoveConverter(this.GetType());

    protected virtual T? Read<T>(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) => 
        (T?)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);

    protected virtual void Write<T>(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) => 
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, modifiedOptions);

    public sealed override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var converterType = (HandleNull ? typeof(NullHandlingDefaultConverter<>) : typeof(DefaultConverter<>)).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert);
        return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType, new object [] { ModifyOptions(options), this })!;
    }
    
    protected virtual bool HandleNull { get; } = false;
}

public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions CopyAndRemoveConverter(this JsonSerializerOptions options, Type converterType)
    {
        var copy = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        for (var i = copy.Converters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (copy.Converters[i].GetType() == converterType)
                copy.Converters.RemoveAt(i);
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Then add it to options as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    // Add NullToDefaultConverter() before any other converters that may apply such as JsonStringEnumConverter()
    Converters = { new NullToDefaultConverter() /*, new JsonStringEnumConverter() */ },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    // Modify other properties as required,
    WriteIndented = true,
};
```

And deserialize as follows:

```
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ComplexClass>(json, options);
```

Now `null` values will be mapped to default values for all non-nullable value types.

Notes:

- The converter works for both constructor arguments (e.g. record arguments) and settable properties.
- The converter does not exactly reproduce the Json.NET's [`NullValueHandling.Ignore`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) functionality.<sup>[1]</sup>  When `NullValueHandling.Ignore` is enabled, Json.NET **skips** null values.  If your model included properties with initialized defaults, e.g.:

  ```
  public class Model
  {
      public int Value { get; set; } = 32;
  }
  ```

  Then with Json.NET the value when deserializing `{"Value" : null}` would remain 32.  With the System.Text.Json converter above, it will be set to `default(int)`.

  (This is what was required by the question, which asked *how to set default value for object property with default value when Json property is null?*)
- The converter will apply to values inside collections as well as property values.  If this is not OK you will need to apply the converter manually to each property or create a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to automatically apply it to all properties.
- In order to work correctly, you need to add `NullToDefaultConverter` to [`JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters) before other converters that might apply, such as `JsonStringEnumConverter`.  As long as you do, `NullToDefaultConverter` will be invoked first to handle nulls, then the subsequent converter will be invoked to do any further necessary conversion.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/otN5Tw).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For confirmation that there is no direct equivalent to `NullValueHandling.Ignore` in System.Text.Json, see [IgnoreNullValues does not work with non-nullable value types #30795](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30795).