# DotNet Core upgrade Issue with JSON Serializer for Property having NULL values

Tags: .net-core, json.net

My application was working fine with .net4.5 but after upgrade to .net6. the application is getting failed due to null value passed into non nullable properties. Model binding is getting null after upgrade.

I have added

```
options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

in pipeline, it is removing all null properties from JSON and properly loading Model but this created another issue by removing null property from response JSON as `NullValueHandling.Ignore` works on both serialization and deserialization.

How can I change this newtonsoft behavior to apply only on serialization, so that while response it should not remove null property?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically how you are enabling Json.NET and invoking the serializer.  asp.net-core uses System.Text.Json by default so you need to be sure you are not using it instead of Json.NET.

Comment: Incidentally, you are using .NET 6 but if you were using .NET 7 you could configure it to convert null values to default values for non-nullable value types.  See [how to set default value for object property with default value when Json property is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77031669/3744182) for how.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected IActionResult CreateResponse<T>(HttpStatusCode code, T response)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        };
        var camelCaseLoad = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, settings);

        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = camelCaseLoad,
            ContentType = Constant.ApplicationJsonType,
            StatusCode = (int)code
        };
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).