# Endless loop during serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

I need to return an object to the client that contains a field of the `VMoney` class

```cs
public class VMoney
{
    public Decimal Value { get; }

    public VMoney(Decimal value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

And I have inherited class `LimitedVMoney`:

```cs
public class LimitedVMoney : VMoney
{
    public DateTime? BeginDateTime { get; }
    public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; }

    public LimitedVMoney(Decimal value, DateTime? beginDateTime, DateTime? endDateTime) : base(value)
    {
        if (beginDateTime is null && endDateTime is null) throw new ArgumentException();
        BeginDateTime = beginDateTime;
        EndDateTime = endDateTime;
    }
}
```

Since when sent to the client, either `VMoney` or `LimitedVMoney` can be sent, so I created `VMoneyConverter : JsonConverter<VMoney>`

```cs
public class VMoneyConverter : JsonConverter<VMoney>
{
    public override VMoney? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
        {
            var root = doc.RootElement;
            root.TryGetProperty("beginDateTime", out JsonElement beginDateTimeElement);
            root.TryGetProperty("endDateTime", out JsonElement endDateTimeElement);

            DateTime? beginDateTime = beginDateTimeElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String
                ? beginDateTimeElement.GetDateTime()
                : null;

            DateTime? endDateTime = endDateTimeElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.String
                ? endDateTimeElement.GetDateTime()
                : null;

            Decimal value = root.GetProperty("value").GetDecimal();

            return VMoneyFactory.Create(value, beginDateTime, endDateTime);
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, VMoney value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if(value is LimitedVMoney limitedVMoney)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, limitedVMoney, options);
            return;
        }

        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }
}
```

And it turns out that if the class is `VMoney` when serialized, then it will endlessly enter the `Write` method, after which the application will crash.

I’ll explain why the decision was initially made to write a custom converter.

If `VMoney` was sent, then it came perfectly with the Value field as it should be, but if `LimitedVMoney` was sent, then it came with the Value field, but without `BeginDateTime`, `EndDateTime`.

And having written a converter, as a result, `LimitedVMoney` comes correctly with all the fields, but `VMoney` does not come due to looping.

Comment: Your call to `JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, limitedVMoney, options);` is identical to the call-site below it. You can remove your `Write` method entirely: `JsonSerializer.Serialize` does not use _static_ type information.

Comment: `root.TryGetProperty` <-- You need to check if `TryGetProperty` returns `false` and act accordingly.

Comment: @Dai, your first comment helped me, thank you. It didn’t occur to me to remove this call, because this is written in every our custom converter

Comment: `using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))` <-- Doing this is inefficient and wasteful - instead you should use the `Read...` methods on `reader`.

Comment: @Dai
I was wrong It still doesn’t work: if VMoney arrives, it return empty vMoney in serialization

Comment: Please post a full example that reproduces the problem, including input JSON, to https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @Dai, https://dotnetfiddle.net/m3qFkC

Comment: That dotnetfiddle doesn't include sample input JSON and running the program as-is results in nothing being written to `stdout`.

Comment: You need to rethink your `override void Write` method, right now you get an empty-string if you try to serialize a non-`LimitedMoney` `VMoney` object.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074304/is-polymorphic-deserialization-possible-in-system-text-json

Comment: It's not actually an endless loop, it's a stack overflow.  To avoid it, see [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182).  But now that System.Text.Json has built-in support for polymorphism I would use that instead as suggested by @Dai, see [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).

Comment: Why are you using a custom converter instead of just using the [JsonDerivedType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0) attributes? I think that would be both easier and more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to the official document to learn [how to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true                        
};
   
VMoney limitedVMoney = new LimitedVMoney(100, new DateTime(), new DateTime());
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(limitedVMoney,limitedVMoney.GetType(), serializeOptions));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(limitedVMoney, serializeOptions));
```

If you must custom JsonConverter, you could modify your code like below:

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, VMoney value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
     if (value is LimitedVMoney limitedVMoney)
     {
         JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, limitedVMoney, options);
         return;
     }

     writer.WriteStartObject();

     writer.WriteNumber("Value", value.Value);
     writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your decision and for the article (when I was looking for info, I didn’t come across it)

Comment: the most interesting thing from the documentation: cases do not work with JsonSerializer<object> and JsonSerializer(value, value.GetType(), options)