In System.Text.Json is it possible to minify only array items?
Using System.Text.Json, is it possible to serialise an array such that each array item appears on a new line but each line is minified? Here is my console app attempting to use Utf8JsonWriter to write each array item.
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace JsonArraySerialisationTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // create test items to be serialised
            const int itemCount = 2;
            List<ExpandoObject> items = new List<ExpandoObject>();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; ++i)
            {
                dynamic item = new ExpandoObject();
                item.prop1 = i;
                item.prop2 = (char)('a' + i);
                items.Add(item);
            }

            string outputJson;
            using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                JsonWriterOptions writeArrayOptions = new JsonWriterOptions()
                {
                    Indented = true,
                };

                JsonSerializerOptions writeItemOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
                {
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                    WriteIndented = false,
                };

                // write items
                using (Utf8JsonWriter jw = new Utf8JsonWriter(outputStream, writeArrayOptions))
                {
                    jw.WriteStartArray();
                    foreach (ExpandoObject item in items)
                    {
                        JsonSerializer.Serialize(jw, item, writeItemOptions);
                    }
                    jw.WriteEndArray();
                }

                // read json string
                outputStream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(outputStream, leaveOpen: true))
                {
                    outputJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(outputJson);
        }
    }
}

The output is
[
  {
    "prop1": 0,
    "prop2": "a"
  },
  {
    "prop1": 1,
    "prop2": "b"
  }
]

If I replace JsonSerializer.Serialize(jw, item, writeItemOptions); with jw.WriteRawValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item, writeItemOptions), true); then the output becomes
[{"prop1":0,"prop2":"a"},{"prop1":1,"prop2":"b"}
]

The output that I would like is
[
  {"prop1":0,"prop2":"a"},
  {"prop1":1,"prop2":"b"}
]

The use case is that my JSON file contains an array with thousands of items and each item will be run through a long-running process. If the processor reports that item 50 caused an error, I would like to be able to manually edit the JSON file to remove all array items except item 50 and debug this single item. If each array item is on its own line then it's simple to delete the unwanted lines/items.
EDIT:
This is not a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question tries to write all array items in a single line. My question is how to write individual array items in a single line but each array item on a separate line.
dbc's link uses Utf8JsonWriter to write a raw JSON value which is what I am trying to do here. When I use JsonSerializer.Serialize(jw, item, writeItemOptions);, the JsonWriterOptions.Indented = true property overrides JsonWriterOptions.Indented = false so the entire JSON file is indented. When I use jw.WriteRawValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item, writeItemOptions), true); then the opening [ doesn't append a newline whereas the closing ] does prepend a newline and each array item is written to the same line. The question is whether it is possible to write each array item to a separate line while retaining each line's minified format.

That's beautification, not minification. JSON doesn't care about whitespace outside string values. STJ doesn't perform beautification

You may be able to use a custom JsonConverter to modify how arrays alone are serialized.

No directly, but you can make a custom JsonConverter that serializes the inner objects to a non-indented string, then writes the raw string.  See In System.Text.Json is it possible to specify custom indentation rules?.

As explained in In System.Text.Json is it possible to specify custom indentation rules?, System.Text.Json does not support custom indentation for individual JSON items when writing to a Utf8JsonWriter stream.  If you want a given item to be indented differently than the overall JSON output, you must generate nested JSON for yourself, then write it to the current writer with Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue().
Since you want array items indented and on a separate line but without any internal indentation, you may do so by constructing the required indentation yourself and prepending it to the raw value before writing it.  For instance, if I modify NoIndentationConverter<T> from this answer to include the required indentation as follows:
public class NoIndentationConverter<T> : DefaultConverterFactory<T>
{
    protected override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) 
    {
        // TODO: investigate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.highperformance.buffers.arraypoolbufferwriter-1
        var bufferWriter = new ArrayBufferWriter<byte>();
        Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[4];
        // Prepend the indentation that comes before the current value.
        foreach (var rune in writer.GetCurrentUtf8Indent(includeNewline : true))
        {
            int length = rune.EncodeToUtf8(buffer);
            bufferWriter.Write(buffer.Slice(0, length));
        }
        // Then serialize the current value without indentation
        using (var innerWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(bufferWriter))
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(innerWriter, value, modifiedOptions);
        // And write the raw value without.
        writer.WriteRawValue(bufferWriter.WrittenSpan, skipInputValidation : true);
    }

    protected override JsonSerializerOptions ModifyOptions(JsonSerializerOptions options) { (options = base.ModifyOptions(options)).WriteIndented = false; return options; }
}

public abstract class DefaultConverterFactory<T> : JsonConverterFactory
{
    // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430420/how-to-use-default-serialization-in-a-custom-system-text-json-jsonconverter
    class DefaultConverter : JsonConverter<T> 
    {
        readonly JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions;
        readonly DefaultConverterFactory<T> factory;

        public DefaultConverter(JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, DefaultConverterFactory<T> factory) => (this.modifiedOptions, this.factory) = (modifiedOptions, factory);

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Write(writer, value, modifiedOptions);
        public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);
    }

    protected virtual JsonSerializerOptions ModifyOptions(JsonSerializerOptions options) 
        => options.CopyAndRemoveConverter(this.GetType());

    protected virtual T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions)
        => (T?)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);

    protected virtual void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) 
        => JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, modifiedOptions);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(T) == typeToConvert;

    public sealed override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => new DefaultConverter(ModifyOptions(options), this);
}

public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Rune> GetCurrentUtf8Indent(this Utf8JsonWriter writer, bool includeNewline = true)
    {
        if (!writer.Options.Indented || writer.CurrentDepth == 0)
            return Array.Empty<Rune>();
        var indentCharacter = ' '; // In .NET 9 use Utf8JsonWriter.IndentCharacter;
        var indentSize = 2;        // In .NET 9 use Utf8JsonWriter.IndentSize;
        var runes = Enumerable.Range(0, indentSize * writer.CurrentDepth).Select(i => new Rune(indentCharacter));
        if (includeNewline)
            runes = Environment.NewLine.EnumerateRunes().Concat(runes);
        return runes;
    }

    public static JsonSerializerOptions CopyAndRemoveConverter(this JsonSerializerOptions options, Type converterType)
    {
        var copy = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        for (var i = copy.Converters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (copy.Converters[i].GetType() == converterType)
                copy.Converters.RemoveAt(i);
        return copy;
    }
}

I can serialize your List<ExpandoObject> as follows:
JsonSerializerOptions writeItemOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Converters = 
    {
        { new NoIndentationConverter<ExpandoObject>() },
    },
    WriteIndented = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};              

JsonSerializer.Serialize(outputStream, items, writeItemOptions);

And the output is, as required:
[
  {"prop1":0,"prop2":"a"},
  {"prop1":1,"prop2":"b"}
]

Notes:

.NET 9 plans to introduce JsonSerializerOptions.IndentCharacter and JsonSerializerOptions.IndentSize.  When you upgrade to that or a later release, JsonSerializerExtensions.GetCurrentUtf8Indent() will need to be upgraded to use the new properties.

As noted in JSON RFC 8259, whitespace between structural characters (such as the whitespace in your custom indentation scheme) is insignificant and will be ignored by receiving systems.


Demo fiddle here.

Thanks, this does exactly what I want. It's suprisingly more code than I originally thought would be needed.

@ElGordo - I reckon it's because Utf8JsonWriter is sealed and has no extension points.  For comparison, Newtonsoft.Json's JsonTextWriter is unsealed so you can create your own custom indentation schemes.  See e.g. How do you limit indentation depth when serializing with Newtonsoft.Json.
