Configure .Net 8 to parse json like .Net Framework 4.8 did?
While porting an application to .NET 8 the Json parser is so much more picky about the Json. How do I tell it to not be so picky? I don't have control over the front end doing the posting.
The post request:
POST http://localhost/SimplePost HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json

{ "Name": "WTF", "Id": null }

The model:
public class SimpleModel
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public long Id { get; set; }
}

.NET Framework 4.8
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SimplePost(SimpleModel m)
{
    return View();
}

Result:
Id = 0
Name = "WTF"


The same in .NET 8:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SimplePost([FromBody] SimpleModel m )
{
    return View();
}

Result in .NET 8:
m is NULL


I tried

Adding defaults in the constructor public SimpleModel() { Name = string.Empty; Id = 1;} public long Id { get; set; } = 1;
Adding defaults to the properties public string name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
Adding decoration to the properties [DefaultValue(0)] [DefaultValue("")]
Adding decoration to the properties [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)] [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
Searching. ;)


If it is not problem to change long Id type to long? Id, implement set method where null become 0.

You can write your own JsonConverter, which needed implementation can be found here: how to set default value for object property with default value when Json property is null?
Here is said implementation by @dbc - of course you can augment it to handle only long in only specific way, below solution is general, which handles more such conversion more broadly:
public class NullToDefaultConverter : DefaultConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert) == null;
    protected sealed override bool HandleNull { get; } = true;
    protected override T? Read<T>(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) where T:default => 
        reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.Null => default(T),
            _ => base.Read<T>(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions),
        };
}

public abstract class DefaultConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430420/how-to-use-default-serialization-in-a-custom-system-text-json-jsonconverter
    class DefaultConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> 
    {
        readonly JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions;
        readonly DefaultConverterFactory factory;

        public DefaultConverter(JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, DefaultConverterFactory factory) => (this.modifiedOptions, this.factory) = (modifiedOptions, factory);

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Write(writer, value, modifiedOptions);
        public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => factory.Read<T>(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);
    }
    class NullHandlingDefaultConverter<T> : DefaultConverter<T>
    {
        public NullHandlingDefaultConverter(JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions, DefaultConverterFactory factory) : base(modifiedOptions, factory) { }
        public override bool HandleNull => true;
    }

    protected virtual JsonSerializerOptions ModifyOptions(JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        options.CopyAndRemoveConverter(this.GetType());

    protected virtual T? Read<T>(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) => 
        (T?)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);

    protected virtual void Write<T>(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions) => 
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, modifiedOptions);

    public sealed override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var converterType = (HandleNull ? typeof(NullHandlingDefaultConverter<>) : typeof(DefaultConverter<>)).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert);
        return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType, new object [] { ModifyOptions(options), this })!;
    }
    
    protected virtual bool HandleNull { get; } = false;
}

public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions CopyAndRemoveConverter(this JsonSerializerOptions options, Type converterType)
    {
        var copy = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        for (var i = copy.Converters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (copy.Converters[i].GetType() == converterType)
                copy.Converters.RemoveAt(i);
        return copy;
    }
}

Then in your startup class (Program or Startup) you register the converter:
// For controllers.
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Insert(
        0,
        new NullToDefaultConverter());
});

// For other, such as Minimal API.
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Insert(
        0,
        new NullToDefaultConverter());
});


Two issues:

Your Id doesn't allow nulls
Your casing doesn't follow JSON defaults

You can change this pretty easily by updating your SimpleModel class:
public class SimpleModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
    public long? Id { get; set; }
}

Make Id nullable, and define the JSON property names to use with attributes. Default JSON naming convention is "camelCase" (initial letter lowercase) - so "name" and "id" would be the default names for JSON properties
I believe this change in behavior is mostly due to switching from Newtonsoft's JSON.NET to the built-in System.Text.Json code base.
You could also globally define System.Text.Json to use case-insensitive property names when deserialising - by specifying this in your program.cs:
builder.Services
       .AddControllers()
       .AddJsonOptions(options =>
           {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
           }); 

According to the MS docs, this might incur a slight performance penalty (because property matching isn't done with an exact match anymore) - but it might be an easier way than having to decorate all your classes with JsonPropertyName attributes...
Learn more about the differences between JSON.NET and System.Text.Json and how to overcome them here:
Migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json

Casing... I don't have control over the front end doing the posting. :/

Making the model allow nulls did the trick. The system.Text.Json parser seems to already be case insensitive.

@JoeMcAlly "The system.Text.Json parser seems to already be case insensitive." - not fully correct. It is ASP.NET Core setting which uses JsonSerializerOptions.Web which is case-insetnsitive
